# Creating new Pandas Dataframe column within pipeline process

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pipeline, preprocessor

I apologize but I'm not sure how to explain this without just giving my example, therefore:

For the titanic dataset in Kaggle, some people have added a new column called 'isChild' and applied it to the age column to where if the age is under 13 he is a child or else he/she is an adult. From there they are fine to preprocess and create and tune their model.

If I were to create that same model and deploy it to where anyone can fill a form on the frontend with the **original** inputs of the Dataframe, the model wouldn't work because the 'isChild' is computed during the preprocessing part.

I understand people use Pipeline and make_pipline to create a process but my question here is that people always add the generic steps in the Pipeline like PCA or imputing missing values. How do I add a step that adds this new column and then runs it through the model?

if you can guide me or link me with something helpful or answer this question it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And to answer your question, you need to create a new column in the data frame using a logic like `df['isChild'] = df['Age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < 13 else 0)`. This will create a new column `isChild` in the `df` wherever value of `age` is less than 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to my question is that I first must create a class, like so:

```
class DataframeFunctionTransformer():
def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func

def transform(self, input_df, **transform_params):
    return self.func(input_df)

def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    return self
```

Then once this class is created, I can create my own function, which was to add a new column (the isChild column) to the titanic Dataframe:

```
def ischild(dataset):
dataset['Child'] = dataset['Age'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x<13 else 'No')

return dataset
```

Now when creating a pipline using sklearn I can use my new function like so:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("ChildColumn", DataframeFunctionTransformer(ischild))
])
```

Thank you.